# Use of the word 'feed' for visitors

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Do we feed people? Does the word 'feed' fit best when we talk about guests or visitors?
Here is the sentence:

> This organization feeds thousands of people who attend training sessions here.

Shouldn't we say:

> This organization serves thousands of people with food who attend training sessions here.

Or there could be some other choice as well?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest restructuring your sentence:

> This organization **provided catering** (that is, they *catered food*)] to the people who attended the training session.

According to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cater):

> **cater** (*verb*) to provide food and drinks for an occasion or event:
>    *Who catered your party?*

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear why you think the verb "feed" is incorrect or inappropriate here. When an organization provides food to people, it feeds them. Yes, one could say "caters" or "provides food" or "serves meals" or "furnishes lunches" or any of several other possibilities. None of these is incorrect. But they mostly add words without adding information. The verb "cater" places the emphasis on the arrangements rather than on the food -- which is fine if that is what the speaker wants to emphasize.

In the related but not identical case of a charity that provides food to those in need, the verb "feed" is by far the most commonly used. Or in a purely social context, one might say:

> We spent the evening with our friends John and Jane, and they fed us very well.

I think the original sentence is as good a way to convey the concept as any, and better than some alternatives.